# Minimizing using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I was given the question:

> Consider the point $P = (3, 4, 0)$ and the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$. Determine the point on the cone that minimizes the square of the distance between $P$ and the cone.

Am I supposed to be minimizing the distance formula between point $P$ and the equation of the cone?

Comment: yes, minimise $(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 + z^2$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$f(x,y)=(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2+x^2+y^2$$
It is $$f(x,y)\geq \frac{25}{2}$$ and the equal sign holds if $$x=\frac{3}{2},y=2$$

Comment: Thank you for the help. I realized my mistake.